# use agg func instead of group by

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, oracle11g

If you have a long select list and a sum(case when then else end) for the last column you will need to put all the selected columns in the group by.  Alternatively you could just put an agg func like min,max... around every column in the select to avoid the group by.  is there any reason to use one approach over the other?

Oracle 11g

```
select
  a.col0,
  a.col1,
  a.col2,
  a.col3,
  sum(a.aggcol)
from...
where...
group by
  a.col0,
  a.col1,
  a.col2,
  a.col3
;
```

OR

```
select
  a.col0,
  min(a.col1),
  min(a.col2),
  min(a.col3),.....
  sum(a.aggcol)
from...
where...
group by
  a.col0
;
```

Comment: You'll get very different results as one will give you the `min()` of each column in the result, and the other will group by each column in the result.  If all of your columns that you throw a `min` on are the same for the selection, then I guess you would get the same results... It's an odd question.

Comment: What are you GROUPing BY in the first query? SUM(....) by itself doesn't mean anything, with a CASE expression in it or without.

Comment: @JNevill Yes col0 is unique and all other cols will just be a static value that will not change with agg.

Comment: @mathguy sorry you're correct that was for example 2.

Comment: Then run both and grab an explain plan. I would imagine if it's smaller data, it would be a wash.

Comment: It was provided by a vendor and I'm just not clear why you'd do it.  I don't see it saving "coding" time as you would need to wrap every col in min() as opposed to just copy and pasting the select to the group by...was curious if there was a simple reason known to those with more experience than me.

Comment: I'd say "no, it is not a common technique known to experienced developers". I am not experienced either, but I've never seen that either here or on OTN or AskTom, and I assume I would have seen it by now.

Comment: @mathguy WOW the cost is significantly in favour of wrapping the cols in agg func as oppoosed to putting in the group by! Crazy.  I will post the whole query as an answer and show cost for both plans.  I only used 6 values in select and difference is 5900557 with agg and 6052890 in group by.  Full Query is 160 in select...

Comment: Run the queries to see if one is faster than the other. Cost is not a reliable indication of time, especially for different queries (and they ARE different, even though they do the same thing). Costs were created to compare different execution plans for the SAME query.

Comment: @mathguy with agr func query is twice as fast...very interesting stuff!

Comment: And it produces the same result? For example, the same number of rows? That would be very interesting.

Comment: **(1)** Why on earth are you aggregating if `a.col0` is unique?!

Comment: **(2)** This pattern is usually an indication that you should have done an aggregation before doing a join

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I'm going to ask the vendor.  The query just selects 20 or so columns with unique static data and then about 50 case when statements.  They've wrapped all but 5 columns in sum()...